# How to use value from a text file with the `set` method of a tkinter Scale widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, save, load, tkinter-scale

I have created a file which saves the values of 2 sliders. Now, I want to be able to recall values from this file to set the value of the sliders.

This is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path
master= Tk()
master.geometry('500x500+0+0')



def print_value(val):
    print ("c1="+str (c1v.get()))
    print ("c2="+str(c2v.get()))


c1v=DoubleVar()
c2v=DoubleVar()

c1 = Scale(master, from_=255, to=0, length =400,width =100, troughcolor = 'blue',command=print_value, variable =c1v)
c1.grid(row=1,column=1)
c2 = Scale(master, from_=255, to=0, length =400,width =100, troughcolor = 'blue',command=print_value, variable =c2v)
c2.grid(row=1,column=2)

def record():

    save_path = 'C:/Users/Josh Bailey/Desktop/pi_dmx'
    name_of_file = ("my first file ")
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")
    file1 = open(completeName , "w")
    toFile = ("c1="+str (c1.get())+ "\n""c2="+str(c2.get()))
    file1.write(toFile)
    file1.close()
    master.mainloop()

rec=Button(master, text="Record",width=20, height=10, bg='Red', command=record)
rec.grid(row=2, column=3)

load=Button(master, text="Load",width=20, height=10, bg='gold')
load.grid(row=2, column=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of the slider like so:

`c1.set(100) #sets value to 100`

So just read a text file and replace 100 in my example with the values from the file:

the code:

```
try:
    f = open("my first file.txt")
    for each_line in f:
        (slider, value) = each_line.split("=")
        if slider == "c1":
            saved_c1 = value
        if slider == "c2":
            saved_c2 = value
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

c1.set(saved_c1)
c2.set(saved_c2)
```

You also have a trailing space after your file name(my first file). It would probably be best to get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a function to get the data out of the file and then hook up this function to `load`.

Following your style, the function would be something like this:

```
def func():

    save_path = 'C:/Users/Josh Bailey/Desktop/pi_dmx'
    name_of_file = ("my first file ")
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")
    file1 = open(completeName)
    val1, val2 = (x.split("=")[1] for x in file1)
    c1v.set(val1)
    c2v.set(val2)
    file1.close()
```

And then you would hook it up to `load` using the button's `command` option:

```
load=Button(master, text="Load",width=20, height=10, bg='gold', command=func)
load.grid(row=2, column=4)
```

---

All in all, the code should be something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path
master= Tk()
master.geometry('500x500+0+0')



def print_value(val):
    print ("c1="+str (c1v.get()))
    print ("c2="+str(c2v.get()))


c1v=DoubleVar()
c2v=DoubleVar()

c1 = Scale(master, from_=255, to=0, length =400,width =100, troughcolor = 'blue',command=print_value, variable =c1v)
c1.grid(row=1,column=1)
c2 = Scale(master, from_=255, to=0, length =400,width =100, troughcolor = 'blue',command=print_value, variable =c2v)
c2.grid(row=1,column=2)

def record():

    save_path = 'C:/Users/Josh Bailey/Desktop/pi_dmx'
    name_of_file = ("my first file ")
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")
    file1 = open(completeName , "w")
    toFile = ("c1="+str (c1.get())+ "\n""c2="+str(c2.get()))
    file1.write(toFile)
    file1.close()
    master.mainloop()

rec=Button(master, text="Record",width=20, height=10, bg='Red', command=record)
rec.grid(row=2, column=3)

#################################################################
def func():

    save_path = 'C:/Users/Josh Bailey/Desktop/pi_dmx'
    name_of_file = ("my first file ")
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")
    file1 = open(completeName)
    val1, val2 = (x.split("=")[1] for x in file1)
    c1v.set(val1)
    c2v.set(val2)
    file1.close()

load=Button(master, text="Load",width=20, height=10, bg='gold', command=func)
load.grid(row=2, column=4)
###################################################################
record()
```

---

Also, just a tip: you should use Python's [with-statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)  when opening files.  It auto-closes them for you.

Comment: i have tried to use your code but get the following error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, the file is definately there i can see it and the path has been copied from the part that creates the file. Why am i getting this error?
heres the code.
def func():
    pass
    file1 = open("C:/Users/Josh Bailey/Desktop/pi_dmx/preset_test.txt")
    val1, val2 = (x.split("=")[1] for x in file1)
    c1.set(val1)
    c2.set(val2)
    file1.close()

Comment: @user2996828 - There are a two things that could be the problem.  1) I see a `pass` in your code.  That shouldn't be there.  2) Your code is using `preset_test.txt` but your other function is making a file named `my first file .txt`.  See my edit.  I added what the full code should look like.  It should work.